# Does the 'genisoimage' command checksum the generated image against the source folder?

Tags: iso, checksum, mkisofs

When generating an ISO image using the `genisoimage` command (apparently "[a carbon copy of `mkisofs`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557910/difference-between-mkisofs-and-genisoimage)"):

`genisoimage -o image.iso path/to/source/directory`

Is a checksum or other type of verification done by this command to ensure that the ISO contents exactly match the contents of the source directory?

I'm currently checking the success of this operation by looking at the exit code, but I have a concern about a theoretical rare case where (even if only in extreme situations such as old/failing hard drives) the command completes with an exit code of `0`, but the contents of the generated image do not exactly match the contents of the source directory.

Comment: `genisoimage` is based in the mkisofs sources from 2004. To make it unique, plenty of bugs have been added while the original program fixed plenty of bugs, added a lot of new functionality and enhanced the performance. My advise is to use a recent original and if you are not sure, call `mkisofs -version` and check whether there is a `Copyright Jörg Shilling` inside the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, and there's not much point in it doing so: a checksum is only useful if it provides independent verification. In this case, you'd effectively be checking the result of two successive reads of the same files; if you can't trust your storage to produce the same result twice, which reads are you going to trust to produce your image?

If you want to verify a generated image, you should extract it (*e.g.* using `7z`) and compare the extracted files with the originals.